# JavaFX: Animate (fade) background of tablecell

Tags: java, css, animation, javafx-2, javafx

is there any way to access the background-color of a JavaFX `TableCell`, so it can be animated somehow like this:

```
FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), [insert Object here]);
```

The goal is to have it blink for half a second after successfully editing it...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: may be helpful ,https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2310537

Comment: Although not what I expected: nice workaround, thanks for the link! This is working fabulously :-)